# Connecting my laptop with my phone via bluetooth in ftp mode

Tags: bluetooth, ftp

I am not able to play or transfer any media file in my laptop when connected to my moto g phone in ftp mode using bluetooth.My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

**On your phone**, making sure that the phone and the computer are linked via Bluetooth properly (they each see the other), transfer the file to the computer.

I repeat (learned this the hard way myself, just now): transfer the files from the phone to the computer. Some phones will allow you to do multiple files at once, some won't. I'm using an LG440g, and I have successfully transferred my photos and videos. The folder they go to will be /home/USER/Public.

For whatever reason, FTP mode does not work for transferring files at the moment, though it does work in Windows using BlueFTP.

Hope that helps.